# VB6 Form will not resize when I run

Tags: vb6

I have to make some modifications to a VB6.0 project that I haven't touched in years so my memory is getting a little old.

I have a form and then I make the form bigger in the IDE.  When I run the program, the size increase does not show up although it looks perfectly fine in the IDE.

What could be causing this?

If I change other stuff on the same form, the changes show up when I run.  The only thing this is happening with is the size.

This form is a lot smaller that the main window so there is space to expand into.

Other forms in my project do not have this same behavior.

What else could I check for?

Comment: Look for something that sets the height and width in code ***at runtime***.  Use the IDE's search specifically to look for ".Height" and ".Width".

Comment: Yes, that's the answer.  Thanks!  Is was done using: Move  value value value value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for something that sets the height and width in code at ***runtime***. Use the IDE's search specifically to look for ".Height" and ".Width" and ".Move".

Comment: +1 took the liberty of editing ".Move" into the answer, which was the culprit in this case

Answer (score 0):

I think that an easier solution might be to set the form's height and width in the form_load event, so it initially becomes as big as desired.